# how to create a dependent value list using javascript validation in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, cascading

If the user chooses the first choice from column A, he sees in column B the choice 1,2,3. If the user chooses the second choice from column A, he sees in column B the choice 4,5.

Conditions:
1.I dont want to use workflows
2.I dont want to use InfoPaths
3.I want to implement this by only using Javascript validation.

I'm new to SharePoint. So please explain it clearly who knows the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success in my code.
Refer this simple example 
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using)

Answer (score 3):

If you neither want to use InfoPath nor Workflow, then you have to use SharePoint web services to fetch corresponding data in Column B for a selected value in dropdown Column B.

You can achieve this functionality using SPServices library. Its a js library used to call SharePoint web services and perform operation very easily and in efficient way.

You have to write script in your Script editor webpart in Newform.aspx page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/address to document library/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/address to document library/jquery.SPServices-0.0.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
   relationshipList: "Cities",
   relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",
   relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
   parentColumn: "Country",
   childColumn: "City",
   debug: true
  });

 });
</script>
```

Here is the link http://www.uccorner.com/253/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down-sharepoint-foundation-2010/ for the same.

Try to download SPSerives-2013 version and JQuery-1.10.1 version. Refrence  these in your webpage. As  there are compatible to each other.

Alternatively, SPServices-0.6 and JQuery 1.6.2 version are compatible to each other.

After referencing these libraries, try simple function **SPGetCurrentUser**

```
    var thisUserAccount = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
});
```

And alert this **thisUserAccount**, If it return value then SPServices is working otherwise not. Then implement your functionality of cascade.

Reference to this link for simple example:-http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser

Comment: Hey ateet thanks for reply.But it doest work for me :-(

Comment: This is basically the go to solution for cascading dropdowns in Sharepoint, the SPServices library. It does require a bit of setup to function properly. What have you done? It does not work for me doesn't really help.

Comment: You have to download SPServices library and jQuery and reference it accordingly. Be careful about conflict of JQuery library versions if it already exist in your masterpage. It cause not to work on it

Comment: I have jquery.SPServices-2014.01,jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min and jquery-1.6.2.min versions.Are they compatible? @ateet

Comment: I think, I could't get what the function does @PirateEric

Comment: Actually there is no code was written for my requirement ( If the user chooses the first choice from column A, he sees in column B the choice 1,2,3.) right? Then how it works? Please explain me frnds.

Comment: @Vanjith I already told you in my above edit answer that SPSErvices 2013 and Jquery 1.10.1 is compatible to each other. SPServices 2014 and JQuery 1.6 can never be compatible, there is so much difference in their release date and accordingly in their version. Try to follow the my above mentioned edited answer related to compatibility of scripts.

Comment: This script will will give you current user. It's simple check to see whether SPService is working or not

Comment: Ateet, instead downloading that jquery versions we can refer it like this(<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
) from other sites directly right?

Comment: yeah sure, you can refer to from cdn too!